# I need to add a variable number of business days to a date

Tags: community, formula, salesforce1-app, custom-object, standard-objects

I have a field in the products called RPG_LeadTime and this is the product lead time before we are expecting to dispatch the product.

So if the date is 23.12.2019 and the lead time it two days then it should show the 26.12.2016 (Just ignore its Christmas)

So i need help creating a formula to get today's date then add the variable number of working days to it to get the new updated dispatch date.

I am being a bit blond today so sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean to use this in a formula field and RPG_LeadTime__c is a number field but the below formula should work for you.

```
TODAY() + RPG_LeadTime__c
```

Comment: Ummm no because if we have the value 6 in he field it’s going to take 8 calander days to dispatch as the 6 will always be business days

Comment: Apologies, I misread the working days part of your question! this will get you close but will not include bank holidays https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91880/date-formula-to-calculate-date-excluding-weekends