# Creating a Formula within a flow to show 2 + business days from flow date

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, datetime

I need to create a formula that shows specifically 2 business days from the flow current date/time.

The formula I currently have is only for 2 days and I am not sure about how to specify 2 business days. This Formula is being used in Flow to auto populate a Target Date field on case that is then used to show an escalation flag warning field. It is required to sit in Flow and not be a Formula field.

Current Formula

```
{!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 2
```

Please advise how I can specifically show 2 business days, not just 2 days.

I tried this formula

```
CASE( 
  MOD({!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 ),
  3, {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 2 + 3,
  4, {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 2 + 3,
  5, {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 2 + 3,
  6, {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 1 + 3,
  {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 3
)
```

And got this error
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date Formula to Calculate date excluding weekends](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91880/date-formula-to-calculate-date-excluding-weekends)

Comment: Please edit your question to add what you have tried beyond the existing basic 2-day formula. If you haven't yet tried anything, give a serious try or two. If that doesn't work, come back & share what you tried & how it is not working (e.g., *exact* error text). This site exists to *help*, not do the work. (From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center: *"We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services."*) Please read more of Help Center & take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have the solution

```
CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE({!$Flow.CurrentDateTime}) - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 ),
  0, {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 1 + 2, /* Sun: {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 1 wknd day + 2 days */
  4, {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 2 + 2, /* Thurs: {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 2 wknd days + 2 days */
  5, {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 2 + 2, /* Fri: {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 2 wknd days + 2 days */
  6, {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 2 + 2, /* Sat: {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 2 wknd days + 2 days */
  {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 2 /* Default (Mon/Tue/Wed): {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} + 2 days */
)
```

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable (actually encouraged) on SFSE that if you found the solution and added it as an answer to your own question, to accept your own answer as the correct or best answer. It helps tidy up the site as well as making it more obvious to future readers.